# Does Twitterbot pass user's language header? [User-Agent]="Twitterbot"

Tags: twitter

I am playing with twitter cards.

The idea is simple - display the card based on user's language.
Now, I am detecting the user agent just fine and generating everything specifically for twitter, but the last part is to set the display language.

Does header ["Accept-Language"] suppose to have anything?
Does twitter pass any user data somehow?

Thank you

Comment: The Twitterbot (card robot) does not set any language data that I am aware of.

Comment: @AndyPiper That is a bummer.Not to sound as John Lennon... Imagen if a single 'summary card' was displaying in the user's language? You twitt a link to Wikipedia, and it get's displayed on twitter in user's language... Anyway, thanks for the answer, I will try to find other way to pull it off.